# How to connect with CT10 bluetooth barcode scanner with android mobile?

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, bluetooth

I have a CT10 bluetooth barcode scanner. At the very beginning  I am able to connect this device with my android phone(4.2.2 android version). First time making connection it ask for the inputting paring code in the mobile screen and after giving that number connection and paring successfully established. But from the the second time when trying to pair the android mobile with the bluetooth device it prompt a paring key which I have to type on the bluetooth device but in the bluetooth device there is no option for entering these key. No I am confused what I have to do. I have followed the tutorial http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WnFEsHXsWjk but it also not working for me. And also I can not connect with other android mobile or laptop for every device it shows the same pop up alert to type the code.

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please see your manual it is written in the manual.

1.> **Power off CT10, and press power key for around 7 seconds, the indicator becomes red.**

2.> **Then power on the CT10 and then scan "Enter Setup"---"Factory Reset", consecutively the indicator becomes red.**

3.> **Turn on Bluetooth  in android devices and search for CT10**

4.> **Input the paring code (Given in the manual like 10010) in the Bluetooth paring request dialog.**

5.> **Click "Next" or "OK" button, you will hear a beep from CT10, the paring successfully. You will find CT10 in the paired devices and is will show connected.**

Lets enjoy with your device.

Hope this answer will help you.

Comment: Thanks for replying. That's work for me. I make this answer as accepted.